# Flutter: How can I add font in flutter project

Tags: flutter

I want use my favorite font in my flutter project. Can anyone help me that how can I add fonts in my project.
thanks.

Comment: This is easy to google: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I do it:

1. Make an assets/fonts folder in the root directory and copy all font files to the font folder as shown below

[image]

2. Now you need to let flutter know that you added those fonts, so mention it in the pubspec.yaml file. (You can check the file it has a pre added commented code for adding font). There just add the font data as shown below

[image]

3. Save the file and vs code will auto run pub get and it's done.

Hope this helps.